# Is illegal to use the Look And Feel of Joomla in a non Open Source Web Application?

Tags: open-source, licensing

I'm developing a propietary (non Open Source) Web Application in ASP.NET, and I want to use the Look And Feel of Joomla (images, control distribution, etc.). Is this illegal? I'm violating the license doing this?

Comment: Prepare for an on-slaught of "you should consult an attorney."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copyright of look and feel [is complicated](http://blog.pastie.org/2008/05/copyright---des.html). You should always consult a lawyer regarding something like this, but I think if you use Joomla an inspiration for a design you write yourself you have nothing to worry about. If you're copying it wholesale or using their graphics files you will be on shakier ground.

In general, I believe graphics files will have stronger copyright protections than a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'd set aside some time and [start reading](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html). Good luck!

EDIT: Joomla is under licensed under GPL if I recall.

Comment: I'm already read it, but it doesn't say anything about images, or mimic the user interface

Answer (score 0):

Unless the images in Joomla are released under a Creative common license, I would avoid using them.

If you want to emulate the look and feel, I think you should be fine. (Note: I am not a lawyer so I might be wrong)